# Контрольная сумма для заголовка IPv4

Tags: c#, ip, сетевое-программирование

Был задан такой вопрос, но я вроде как приблизился к решению вопроса о своей задаче. В интернете найден мной такой метод:

```
        public static ushort ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(byte[] header, int length) {
        ushort word16;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
            word16 = (ushort)(((header[i] << 8) & 0xFF00) + (header[i + 1] & 0xFF));
            sum += word16;
        }

        while ((sum >> 16) != 0) {
            sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
        }

        return (ushort)~sum;
    }
```

Но он не работает как должно, да и к тому же я не понимаю метода вычисления контрольной суммы. С английским у меня не очень хорошо, дабы такие статьи почитать в интернете на другом языке.
Пакет собирается таким образом:

```
            foreach (byte array in MacAddressDestination) {
            Packet[i++] = array;
        }
        foreach (byte array in MacAddressSource) {
            Packet[i++] = array;
        }
        Packet[i++] = 0x08; //IPv4
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Type IPv4
        Packet[i++] = 0x45; //IP Version
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Тип Сервиса //0x41
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Total lenght
        Packet[i++] = 0x3c; //Total lenght
        Packet[i++] = 0x50; //Идентификатор
        Packet[i++] = 0x73; //Идентификатор
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Флаг
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Флаг
        Packet[i++] = 0x80; //TTL
        Packet[i++] = 0x01; //ICMP Protocol 
        //Packet[i++] = 0x35; //Header checksum (Правильная сумма, какая должна получится)
        //Packet[i++] = 0x8d; //Header checksum
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Header checksum
        Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Header checksum
        foreach (byte array in ipS) { //IP адрес источника
            Packet[i++] = array;
        }
        foreach (byte array in ipD) { //IP адрес доставки
            Packet[i++] = array;
        }
        ushort ipHeadChecksum = ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(Packet, 33);//Применение метода
        Packet[24] = (byte)ipHeadChecksum;
        Packet[25] = (byte)(ipHeadChecksum >> 8);
```

Скорее всего ошибка у меня в применении этого метода

Comment: Метод вычисления контрольной суммы у вас правильный, он соответствует [описанию в Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum).

Comment: А вот вот это выглядит подозрительно: `ushort ipHeadChecksum = ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(Packet, 33);`: почему вдруг длина заголовка 33 байта?

Comment: @VladD Она разве не с 0 начинается? Только что порверил вайршарком, 30-33 ip destination

Comment: С нуля, конечно. Но например если ваш пакет занимает байты от 0-го до 33-го, его длина 34.

Comment: Ваша длина заголовка по идее лежит в младшем полубайте нулевого байта, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: @VladD хорошо, исправил, однако в таком случае результат всё равно не верен, он составляет: "D8-83"

Comment: Подождите, так у вас же пакет собирается неправильно! Первый байт должен собираться из двух полубайт: Version (0x4) и Header Length (в двойных словах, то есть длина в байтах / 4). А у вас 0x8.

Comment: Если у вас нету опций, то длина в байтах должна быть по идее 20.

Comment: @VladD вот сбор пакета  с нуля, со всеми входными данными, что у меня есть: https://pastebin.com/16tMg2mH .

Comment: Не, что-то не то. Начальный байт должен быть (`0x04 << 4 + length / 4`). А у вас почему-константа 8. Затем, если у вас нету опций, то length должно быть 20 (не 0x20), так что начальный байт получается 0x45, если я ничего не напутал.

Comment: @VladD так стоп, Wireshark мне подсказывает, что ushort(начальный байт после мак адреса) 0x0800 даёт пакету тип IPv4.К тому же, при правильно указанной чексумме, пакет отсылается нормально и компьютер, который принял этот пакет отвечает на него (пинг-ответ на запрос). В комментарии снимок экрана скинуть не могу. UPD: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4 там написано, что в первом поле сразу идёт версия протокола

Comment: Мне сложно спорить с wireshark, возможно, он показывает вам Ethernet Frame. В любом случае, вот вам ссылка на RFC, которая вроде бы подтверждает моё мнение: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#section-3.1. Ну и MAC-адрес точно в IP-пакет не входит.

Comment: Ага, нашёл! Вы небось составляете не ipv4 header, а ethernet frame, который этот самый ipv4-пакет содержит как payload. Так вот в ethernet frame после MAC-адресов как раз идёт тип пакета, в котором 0x08 означает ipv4. ([Вот тут описание](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Types), смотрите на картинку.)

Comment: Тогда у вас начало IP-датаграммы вот: `Packet[i++] = 0x45; //IP Version`. Соответственно длина пакета 20. Подправляйте :)

Comment: И не забудьте записать точный адрес контрольной суммы. Вместо `Packet[i++] = 0x00; /*Header checksum*/ Packet[i++] = 0x00; /*Header checksum*/` у вас будет `var checkSumStartIdx = i; Packet[i++] = 0x00; /*Header checksum*/ Packet[i++] = 0x00; /*Header checksum*/`, а вместо `            Packet[24] = (byte)ipHeadChecksum; Packet[25] = (byte)(ipHeadChecksum >> 8);` соответственно `Packet[checkSumStartIdx] = (byte)ipHeadChecksum; Packet[checkSumStartIdx+1] = (byte)(ipHeadChecksum >> 8);`.

Comment: @VladD вот насчёт как нужно "подправить" я недопонял, уточните, пожалуйста.Ибо если я что-то меняю вначале, сам пакет весь ломается, ведь я его составлял по шаблону

Comment: Ну, ваш код на деле не собирает IP-датаграмму, он собирает Ethernet-фрейм. А что подправить, это длину пакета на 20 (не 0x20!) `ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(Packet, 20)`, и, возможно, изменения из предыдущего комментария.

Comment: Стойте, и считать длину нужно не от начала же, т. к. у вас IP-датаграмма находится не с нуля! Сейчас напишу, короче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код собирает не IP-датаграмму, а Ethernet-фрейм. Соответственно IPv4-заголовок находится не с начала. Судя по всему, нужны такие изменения:

```
public static ushort ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(byte[] header, int start, int length) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        ushort word16 = (ushort)((header[start + i] << 8) + header[start + i + 1]);
        sum += word16;
    }

    while ((sum >> 16) != 0) {
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
    }

    return (ushort)~sum;
}
```

И ваш код:

```
foreach (byte array in MacAddressDestination) {
    Packet[i++] = array;
}
foreach (byte array in MacAddressSource) {
    Packet[i++] = array;
}
Packet[i++] = 0x08; //IPv4
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Type IPv4

var datagramStart = i; // здесь начинается IPv4-датаграмма
Packet[i++] = 0x45; //IP Version
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Тип Сервиса //0x41
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Total lenght
Packet[i++] = 0x3c; //Total lenght
Packet[i++] = 0x50; //Идентификатор
Packet[i++] = 0x73; //Идентификатор
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Флаг
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Флаг
Packet[i++] = 0x80; //TTL
Packet[i++] = 0x01; //ICMP Protocol
var checksumStart = i; // здесь начинается контрольная сумма
//Packet[i++] = 0x35; //Header checksum (Правильная сумма, какая должна получится)
//Packet[i++] = 0x8d; //Header checksum
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Header checksum
Packet[i++] = 0x00; //Header checksum

foreach (byte array in ipS) { //IP адрес источника
    Packet[i++] = array;
}
foreach (byte array in ipD) { //IP адрес доставки
    Packet[i++] = array;
}
ushort ipHeadChecksum = ComputeHeaderIpChecksum(Packet, datagramStart, 20);
Packet[checksumStart] = (byte)(ipHeadChecksum >> 8);
Packet[checksumStart + 1] = (byte)ipHeadChecksum;
```

Comment: ushort word16 = ((ushort)(header[start + i] << 8) + (ushort)header[start + i + 1]); В этой строке ошибка, тип должен быть long, да и word16 тогда уж ошибочное название, что путает немного. Результат получился, но наоборот, вместо 35-8D получилось 8D-35

Comment: А почему long? Слова ведь складываются 16-битные?

Comment: А по поводу результата, у вас правильная endianness?

Comment: Выдает ошибку преобразование из ushort в int, к тому же, насколько я помню, для подсчёта нужно больше места, чем даёт нам ushort, поэтому и тип другой, только что проверил компилятором, также ещё нужно сменить смещение, ибо у меня оно неправильно, в первом байте должно быть смещение вправо, во втором байте удалить смещение.В итоге должно получится так:"            Packet[checkSumStartIdx] = (byte)(ipHeadChecksum >> 8);
            Packet[checkSumStartIdx + 1] = (byte)ipHeadChecksum;". Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Evgen: Ага, проверил и подправил. Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло!